# Is there a software that can automatically create possible css rules from an html file?

Tags: css

I know that [StyleMaster](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/) has this feature, but is there any free sofware that has it?

Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

[Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) will pull style information out of the tags and put it into embedded CSS.